# asmjit getgpArg(), getxmmArg() and make() replacement

Tags: asmjit

I'm currently working on a legacy codebase which used old asmjit with the intenion of migrating to using the latest asmjit. I've been able to figure out signature replacements e.g. `call`, `setArg` I need help in understanding alternatives for old asmjit functions like `getGpArg`, `getXmmArg` and `make()`.

```
    //old signatures
    X86CompilerFuncCall ctx = c.call(address);
    ctx->setPrototype(kX86FuncConvCompatFastCall, FuncBuilder1<int, int>());
    ctx->setArgument(0, var);
    ctx->setReturn(var);

    //New signature
    auto ctx_new = c.call((uint64_t)address, FunctionSignature1<int, int>());
    ctx_new->SetArg(0, var);
    ctx_new->setRet(0, var);
```

Any suggestions from  `asmjit` users/readers for alternatives to `getGpArg`, `getXmmArg` and `make()` is welcome.

Comment: I would recommend using next-wip branch if you want to port your code to a new asmjit. The current master is in maintenance mode only and will be replaced soon. That would save you a double-porting effort.

Comment: @Petr I'll do that.